# Pandas DataFrame producing unexpected result with list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

When I am using  list comprehension on dataframe to find common elements in each columns.

```
   df
    A   B   C
0   1   2   0
1   3   4   6
2   5   6   7
3   7   3   3
4   9   1   9

    l=[i for i in df.A if i in df.B ]
    l
    [1, 3]
    list2=[i for i in l if i in df.C]
    list2
    [1, 3]
```

first list comprehension  produces the result as expected i.e common element in A and B are [1,3].
But **[i for i in l if i in df.C]** this line produces unexpected result.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the DataFrame column to a list.

```
list2 = [i for i in l if i in list(df.C)]
```

**OR**

```
list2=[i for i in l if i in df.C.tolist()]
```

output of `list2`:

```
>>>print(list2)
[3]
```

This is because df.C returns a Series with index '1' included.

You can also use df.C.values instead.

Comment: Any clarification why we need to convert into list?